# Why is this O(sqrt(n))?

Tags: big-o, discrete-mathematics, coding-efficiency

Can anyone explain why this is O(sqrt(n))? Is the best way to approach this by putting numbers to it?

```
i:=1
p:=0
for (p<n) do 
   p = p+i
   i+=1
```

[Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAhnn.png)

I thought it was O(n), but if I put n = 5, I see that it's not iterating through n times. I'm not sure how to mathematically figure it out without just testing different n values.

Comment: Testing different values is a good approach. You say it's not iterating *n* times: Then how many? Try to find a pattern, and then see if you can express it in terms of *n*.

Comment: Large hint: Sum of an Arithmetic Sequence

Comment: Generally see e.g. this [list of sum identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Powers_and_logarithm_of_arithmetic_progressions) on Wikipedia when trying to figure this out. The second one is what is used in the answer below. I have seen it being called "Gauss's Identity", but there is too many formulas named after Gauss, so it is terrible to search for.

Answer (score 1):

The loop keeps going until it finds the smallest number greater than or equal to `n`. The `nth`  number is given by the formula `n(n+1)/2`. So, what you want to do is find the smallest integer `i` such that `i(i+1)/2` is greater than or equal to `n`. Solving for i:

```
i(i+1)/2 >= n
i^2 + i >= 2n
i^2 + i - 2n >= 0
```

Using the quadratic formula, we can solve for i:

```
i = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8n))/2
```

Since you only care about the integer part of `i`, we can ignore the `-1`term in the numerator and write:

```
i = sqrt(2n + 1/4) - 1/2
```

So, the loop goes through approximately `sqrt(n)` iterations, since you can ignore the constant terms in the square root and the denominator. Therefore, the time complexity of the code is `O(sqrt(n))`.